# How would the Casimir effect work if the metal plate was long enough?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect

Gravitational time dilation is a form of time dilation, an actual difference of elapsed time between two events as measured by observers situated at varying distances from a gravitating mass.

[image]

This has been demonstrated by noting that atomic clocks at differing altitudes (and thus different gravitational potential) will eventually show different times.

In quantum field theory, the Casimir effect is a physical force acting on the macroscopic boundaries of a confined space which arises from the quantum fluctuations of the field.

[image]

If the distance between the metal plates is the same in each experiment, and the time for the Casimir effect to close the metal plate is measured, is the time measured at different heights from the ground the same?

[image]

How would the Casimir effect work if the metal plate was long enough?

[image]

Are quantum fluctuations affected by gravity?

Is zero point energy affected by gravity? Is it higher or lower?

Do event horizons have quantum fluctuations?

Comment: If your question boils down to "does gravity have an effect on the Casimir force," the answer is "yes." In fact, you can turn this around and use measurements of the Casimir force to place bounds on deviations from Newton's law of gravity; see Section 3.6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406024.

Comment: @Andrew What about the quantum fluctuations and zero-point energy that cause the Casimir force?